# Actionscript 3.0 repeating movie three times then running close frames

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an animation that I want to loop three times and then finish the final frames and then stop. I have tried this code to start with:

```
var stopNum = 0;
function looper(loopLimit) {
  if (stopNum>=loopLimit) {
    stop();
  } else {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
  }
  this.stopNum++;
}
```

And this code to stop:

```
if (!loopCount) {
  var loopCount:Number = 0;
}
loopCount++;
if (loopCount >= 3) {
  this.stop();
}
```

I have remaining frames to play from this point and then the entire animation stops. The problem is the frames loop three times but include all the frames including the closing frames.

Comment: What do you mean `but include all the frames including the closing frames.`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using some events available from Flash 10 like so:

`Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED`

and

`Event.EXIT_FRAME`

Throwing some idea though, e.g. If your animation ends, then use `Event.EXIT_FRAME` and keep counter which will tell you that how many times animation is played.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd use an event listener to check for when the playhead advances for the moiveclip (as mentioned by Rajneesh). Within the event listener, I'd check for what frame it is at, and if it is at the end of my 'end loop frame' and then I'd check if I need to loop it. If so, then I increment a counter to keep track of how many times I've looped, and tell the movieclip to go to the start frame and play again.

Once it's looped enough times, I'd just let it run until the last frame then, on which I'd stop the animation.

I'll take a guess and assume your movieclip has 100 frames, and you only want frame 1 to 90 to loop 2 times, then have it play 1 more time, but from frame 1 to 100. Plays a total of three times from 1 to 90, then once 91 to 100, before stopping.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var clip:MovieClip = this.aCircle;

var timesPlayed:int = 0;
var timesToLoop:int = 3;
var frameToStartLoop:int = 1;
var frameToStopLoop:int = 90;

function enterFrameListener(inputEvent:Event):void {
    if(clip.currentFrame == frameToStopLoop){
        timesPlayed++;
        if(timesPlayed < timesToLoop){
            clip.gotoAndPlay(frameToStartLoop);
        }

    // if the currentFrame made it past the above condition, then
    // it means there is no more looping needed so just play till the end and stop.
    } else if(clip.currentFrame == clip.totalFrames){
        clip.stop();
        // can remove this listener now, as it is no longer needed
        clip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameListener, false);
    }
}
// use an event listener to listen for the ENTER_FRAME event, which is triggered everytime the movieclip advances a frame
// (as a side note, you'll also find that this event is triggerd even if there is only 1 frame, or even if the playhead is not actually moving, check the doc for details)
clip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameListener, false, 0, true);
```